# how to install the crystal report in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I want to install crystal report in my mvc project

I am using code first approach

but when I am trying to add crystal report then not showing reporting

[image]

I install this but not showing any reporting menu

[image]

How to install the crystal report in my project mvc

is there any way to install crystal report in mvc project

[image]

Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal report is a third-party reporting tool, you can not install it from visual studio installer.

You may follow the installation steps and documentation from the official site.

Download it from https://www.sap.com/products/crystal-visual-studio.html

Reference documents and source:
https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/SAP_CRYSTAL_REPORTS,_DEVELOPER_VERSION_FOR_MICROSOFT_VISUAL_STUDIO/SP21/en-US

Comment: where is instruction?

Comment: https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/SAP_CRYSTAL_REPORTS,_DEVELOPER_VERSION_FOR_MICROSOFT_VISUAL_STUDIO/SP21/en-US

Comment: still I am not seeing the crystal report in my project not showing the under the Crystal Report->Reporting

Comment: Just make sure that you have followed all the installation steps: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/download-crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2019/

Comment: And here is the tutorial https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/create-crystal-reports-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219174/discussion-between-rahul-and-mehul-rudatala).

Answer (score 0):

this doesnt support .net core, it wont be showing in templates for .net core projects, try mvc5 projects, i have encountered this issue recently